# split string index row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to split INDEX in df by "_"

dataframe is as below:

|  | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| catA_gas | abc | abc |
| catB_green | abc | abc |
| catA_apple | abc | abc |

I would like to make extra column where catA/catB will be separated from the rest of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`Index.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values before first `_`:

```
df['Column3'] = df.index.str.extract(r'([^_]+)', expand=False)
print (df)
           column1 column2 Column3
catA_gas       abc     abc    catA
catB_green     abc     abc    catB
catA_apple     abc     abc    catA
```

Or if need 2 new columns use [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['Column3','Column4']] = df.index.to_series().str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df)
           column1 column2 Column3 Column4
catA_gas       abc     abc    catA     gas
catB_green     abc     abc    catB   green
catA_apple     abc     abc    catA   apple
```

Comment: why did you reopen?

Comment: because working with index.

Comment: It's the same method, you even linked to it…

Comment: @mozway - Sure, I always do it, first test and if no dupe reopened.

Comment: Well it's a duplicate here